# How convert a PHP array of associative array to a CSV string using a third composer vendor lib?

Tags: php, csv, composer-php

I must convert a php associative array to CSV like:

```
[
    ["a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3],
    ["a"=>5, "b"=>6, "c"=>6],
    ["a"=>7, "b"=>8, "c"=>9, "d"=>10]
]
```

must output a string like

```
a;b;c;d
1;2;3;
4;5;6;
7;8;9;10
```

I already implement this logic using only `foreach` and `implodes`. However CSV has some features like knowing when scape chars and when to quote cells.

I've been used https://www.papaparse.com/ (javascript) a lot for the front-end side.

Is there a Composer package which can do the job?

PS. I need the CVS as string not to save to a file.

Comment: Composer? Why do you need composer when you have `fputcsv`?

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: i did not give up yet

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fputcsv` to get properly formatted CSV, saving to memory and then save it to a variable:

```
$fh = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');

foreach($array as $row) {
    fputcsv($fh, $row); // add other args as needed
}
$csv = stream_get_contents($fh, -1, 0);

//or

rewind($fh);
$csv = stream_get_contents($fh);
```

You can also use `php://temp` which will use memory up to a limit and then write to a temporary file or you can generate your own temporary file with `tmpfile`.